# Assembly word is substring of a string problem

Tags: string, assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I need to make this code which displays if a word is a substring of another. Both are read from the keyboard, firstly the string and then the word which I need to check if it's a substring.

The problem is that I input them and the output is:

> Invalid. Word found. Word not found.

I tried to check if the second input is bigger than the first, so basically, it would compare them and display the message: "invalid."  No matter what I write the output is the same: "Invalid. Word found. Word not found."

Here is my full code:

```
.model small
.stack 200h
.data
     prompt1 db "Input String: $"
     prompt2 db 10,10, 13, "Input Word: $"
     prompt3 db 10,10, 13, "Output: $"
     found db "Word Found. $"
     notfound db "Word Not Found. $"
     invalid db 10,10, 13, "Invalid. $"
     InputString db 21,?,21 dup("$")  
     InputWord db 21,?,21 dup("$")
     actlen db ?

.code
start:
      mov ax, @data
      mov ds, ax
      mov es, ax

     ;Getting input string
     mov ah,09h
     lea dx, prompt1
     int 21h

     lea si, InputString
     mov ah, 0Ah
     mov dx, si
     int 21h

     ;Getting input word
     mov ah,09h
     lea dx, prompt2
     int 21h

     lea di, InputWord
     mov ah, 0Ah
     mov dx, di
     int 21h

     ;To check if the length of substring is shorter than the main string
     mov cl, [si+1]
     mov ch, 0
     add si, 2
     add di, 2
     mov bl, [di+1]
     mov bh, 0
     cmp bx, cx
     ja invalid_length
     je valid
     jb matching

valid:
     cld
     repe cmpsb
     je found_display
     jne notfound_display
mov     bp, cx      ;CX is length string (long)
sub     bp, bx      ;BX is length word  (short)
inc     bp

cld
    lea     si, [InputString + 2]
    lea     di, [InputWord + 2]
matching:
    mov     al, [si]    ;Next character from the string
    cmp     al, [di]    ;Always the first character from the word
    je      check
continue:  
    inc     si          ;DI remains at start of the word
    dec     bp
    jnz     matching    ;More tries to do
    jmp     notfound_display

check:
    push    si
    push    di
    mov     cx, bx     ;BX is length of word
    repe cmpsb
    pop     di
    pop     si
    jne     continue
    jmp     found_display

again:
     mov si, ax    
     dec dx
     lea di, InputWord
     jmp matching


invalid_length:
     mov ah, 09h
     lea dx, invalid
     int 21h



found_display:
mov dx, offset found
mov ah, 09h
int 21h



notfound_display:
mov dx, offset notfound
mov ah, 09h
int 21h



end start
```

Comment: Well an obvious problem is that your display blocks fall through into each other which is why you get multiple messages. As for the rest, use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify what Jester has already stated:

```
invalid_length:
     mov ah, 09h
     lea dx, invalid
     int 21h

found_display:
     mov dx, offset found
     mov ah, 09h
     int 21h

notfound_display:
     mov dx, offset notfound
     mov ah, 09h
     int 21h

end start
```

Labels by themselves **do not** affect the operation of the `ip` register. This is because labels don't exist at runtime; they're merely a convenience for the programmer. So what your computer is actually doing with the above code is this:

```
invalid_length:
     mov ah, 09h
     lea dx, invalid
     int 21h
     mov dx, offset found
     mov ah, 09h
     int 21h
     mov dx, offset notfound
     mov ah, 09h
     int 21h

end start
```

If you want only *one* of these three to be run, you need to redirect `ip` at the end of each. There are a few ways to do this, here's one:

```
invalid_length:
     mov ah, 09h
     lea dx, invalid
     int 21h
     jmp done

found_display:
     mov dx, offset found
     mov ah, 09h
     int 21h
     jmp done

notfound_display:
     mov dx, offset notfound
     mov ah, 09h
     int 21h
     ;fallthrough is intentional

done:
     mov ax,4C00h
     int 21h        ;exit program and return to DOS
```